# SQL Subquery Where Column = Column -10

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT

worksorders.id AS 'Works Order No',
worksorders.partid AS 'Part No',
allpartmaster.partdesc AS 'Description',
worksorders.quantity AS 'Qty',
wip.wqleft AS 'Qty Rem',
worksorders.duedate AS 'Due Date',
worksorders.lateststartdate AS 'Latest Start Date',
worksorders.kitstatus AS 'Kit Status',
wip.wopnumber AS 'Op No',
wip.wmachine AS 'Work Centre',
wip.wdesc AS 'WC Description',
wip.wstate as 'Op State',
(SELECT wstate FROM wip WHERE wip.wona = worksorders.id and wip.wopnumber = (wip.wopnumber - 10)) as 'Prev Op State'

FROM efacdb.dbo.allpartmaster allpartmaster, efacdb.dbo.wip wip, efacdb.dbo.worksorders worksorders

WHERE worksorders.id = wip.wona AND allpartmaster.partnum = worksorders.partid AND ((worksorders.status = 'ACTIVE') AND (wip.wstate = 'NS'))

AND wip.wmachine = 'POLISH'

ORDER BY worksorders.lateststartdate ASC
```

I'm having trouble with this query, I'm not sure if it's even possible. I'm returning operations which are numbered in steps of 10, I need to return the status of the previous operation. Here's the key line:

```
(SELECT wstate FROM wip WHERE wip.wona = worksorders.id and wip.wopnumber = (wip.wopnumber - 10)) as 'Prev Op State'
```

I want to take the wopnumber from the parent SELECT query, take 10 off it and return the wstate column of that row.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: You should use different aliases inside the subquery so that you can reference the outer table. You also ought to use ANSI Joins - they've been in the SQL Standard since 1992, a quarter of a *century* ago.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Old school joins apparently have a certain nostalgia, sort of like listening to classic rock :-)

Comment: This is easily doable, but as the others have said, it would really be polishing a turd to show you with that code. Update your code to use ANSI Joins, and put that select in a sub query, or use CTE and you will be able to do it.

Comment: thanks for the help guys i can work it out based off that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT

        worksorders.id AS 'Works Order No',
        worksorders.partid AS 'Part No',
        allpartmaster.partdesc AS 'Description',
        worksorders.quantity AS 'Qty',
        wip.wqleft AS 'Qty Rem',
        worksorders.duedate AS 'Due Date',
        worksorders.lateststartdate AS 'Latest Start Date',
        worksorders.kitstatus AS 'Kit Status',
        wip.wopnumber AS 'Op No',
        wip.wmachine AS 'Work Centre',
        wip.wdesc AS 'WC Description',
        wip.wstate as 'Op State',
        app.wstate as 'Prev Op State'

FROM efacdb.dbo.allpartmaster allpartmaster, efacdb.dbo.wip wip, efacdb.dbo.worksorders worksorders
     cross apply (SELECT wstate 
                  FROM wip wip1 
                  WHERE wip1.wona = worksorders.id and wip1.wopnumber = wip.wopnumber - 10) app

WHERE worksorders.id = wip.wona AND allpartmaster.partnum = worksorders.partid AND ((worksorders.status = 'ACTIVE') AND (wip.wstate = 'NS'))

AND wip.wmachine = 'POLISH'

ORDER BY worksorders.lateststartdate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT
worksorders.id AS [Works Order No],
worksorders.partid AS [Part No],
allpartmaster.partdesc AS [Description],
worksorders.quantity AS [Qty],
wip.wqleft AS [Qty Rem],
worksorders.duedate AS [Due Date],
worksorders.lateststartdate AS [Latest Start Date],
worksorders.kitstatus AS [Kit Status],
wip.wopnumber AS [Op No],
wip.wmachine AS [Work Centre],
wip.wdesc AS [WC Description],
wip.wstate as [Op State],
prevwip.wstate as [Prev Op State]
FROM efacdb.dbo.allpartmaster allpartmaster
JOIN efacdb.dbo.wip wip ON (allpartmaster.partnum = worksorders.partid AND wip.wstate = 'NS' AND wip.wmachine = 'POLISH')
JOIN efacdb.dbo.worksorders worksorders ON (worksorders.id = wip.wona and worksorders.status = 'ACTIVE')
LEFT JOIN efacdb.dbo.wip prevwip ON (prevwip.wona = wip.wona and prevwip.wopnumber = (wip.wopnumber - 10))
ORDER BY worksorders.lateststartdate ASC
```

*Disclaimer: Only tested in notepad*